# Prove a number $u$ is the supremum of $S$ using three properties...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be nonempty. Prove that if a number u in $\mathbb{R}$ has the properties: (i) for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the number $u-\frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound of $S$, and (ii) for every number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the number $u+\frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound of $S$, then $u=\sup S$.

I'll list what I'm confused about at the bottom of the post:

1) To show this is true I first considered the case where for an arbitrary $x\in S$, $x>u$ which implies that $x-u>0\Rightarrow x-u>\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by the archimedean property. This implies that $x>u+\frac{1}{n}$.

2) For the second part let an arbitrary $y\in S$ such that $y<u$ then we have $u-y>0\Rightarrow u-y>\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so we have $u-\frac{1}{n}>y$

I am having a lot of difficulty comprehending why exactly this shows that $u=\sup S$. We have $x>u+\frac{1}{n}$, I want to say then that $x$ cannot be a supremum since $u$ is already one but *that's* what I'm trying to prove. If someone could explain why this proves that $u=\sup S$ that would help a lot!

Comment: You are trying to prove the equivalence of two definitions. In order to do so, it would be a good idea to start by giving the definition of supremum you know to be true.

Comment: $u$ is the supremum of the set if it is the least upper bound such that $\forall s\in S\Rightarrow u\geq s$ or equivalently, $u$ is a supremum of the set $S$ if $\forall \varepsilon >0, u+\varepsilon >t \hspace{3mm}\forall t\in S$

Comment: You need to choose which definition you are going to work with and state it at the beginning of your proof. This will help both you and the reader.

Comment: In this case, I think the best way would be to show that (1) it is an upper bound, (2) everything bellow is not.

Comment: You can derive this from the first definition you have in the comments.

Comment: Can I prove that $u$ is an upper-bound since $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow u+\frac{1}{n}> x \hspace{3mm}\forall x\in S$

Comment: You Will need more details. Show that if x is greater than u than x is not in S.